# How can I add an x to close Pages on a CPropertySheet?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a resizable CPropertySheet which displays CPropertyPages in a tabbed view.  Clients have requested that the CPropertyPage tabs be closable by clicking an x on the tab (similar to google chrome, or Visual Studio itself).  Is there a relatively straightforward way to accomplish this?  I'm using VS2010, if that's pertinent.

Various combinations of Google search terms failed to yield helpful results, and I haven't found an answer in the documentation.

Comment: If you are using MFC (as you are) I think you will need to roll your own (as I did) or find an existing library.

Comment: Have you thought about [adding an "X" icon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6234/High-color-icons-for-CPropertySheet) to the property page tab?

Comment: OP update:  Since I wasn't at liberty to switch to using CMFCTabCtrl, and since I didn't have a weak to hack together a solution, I used a button on the CPropertyPage-derived class.  Thanks for the input, it was quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

.h:

```
CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTab;
```

.cpp:

```
m_wndTab.Create (CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D, rectTab, this, 1, CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);   
m_wndTab.EnableActiveTabCloseButton(); // <-- this adds a X button to the tab
```